# IOS Auto resizing table cells w. expanding popdown menu (like tweetbot)

Tags: ios, uitableview, accordion, expand, autoresize

I know this is probably going to be one big headache, but it needs to be done. I finally got my tableview resizing cells as well as my label in such a way that all the text from each cell is displayed correctly.

NOTE: the comment & bump buttons are NOT the popdown menu I want to displayed when the cell is expanded , those 2 buttons should always be displayed , the menu i want to add would be a set of 4 buttons that would display under those buttons when the cell is expanded

[image]

[image]

[image]

But now I would like to add a pop down menu to each cell like tweetbot, shown below

[image]

But this is proving to be quite difficult due to how i am resizing the label using autolayout constraints. I came across this example of how to implement something similar to Tweetbot that seems pretty simple and practical on github [here](https://github.com/sjbyrd/ExpandingCells).

The problem is this example assumes all cells are the same size and that their is no dynamic sizing to the individual cells.

**PublicFeedViewController.M**

```
#import "PublicFeedViewController.h"
#import "FeedItemCell.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "InboxDetailViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"


@interface PublicFeedViewController (){
    NSArray *NameLabel;
    NSArray *StatusLabel;
    NSMutableArray *feedArray;
}

@end

@implementation PublicFeedViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //The below code prompts the user for push notifications. If allowed, code in AppDelegate takes over and stores the token.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.FeedTable.dataSource=self;
    self.FeedTable.delegate=self;

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
    [manager POST:@"http://" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        self->feedArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"feed"];

        [self.FeedTable reloadData];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return feedArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    FeedItemCell *Cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!Cell){
        Cell = [[FeedItemCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    NSLog(@"FEED ARRAY: %@", self->feedArray);
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self->feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Display recipe in the table cell
    NSString *thumb_img = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"thumb_img"];
    NSString *thumb_path=@"http://";
    NSString *thumb_url = [thumb_path stringByAppendingString:thumb_img];



    Cell.NameLabel.text=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"];




    Cell.StatusLabel.text=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    Cell.msg_id=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"msg_id"];
    //Cell.status=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    Cell.StatusLabel.lineBreakMode=0;
    Cell.StatusLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    NSString *commentCount = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"comment_count"];
    NSString *commentButtonText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Comments ( %@ )",commentCount];
    [Cell.commentButton setTitle:commentButtonText  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *bumpCount = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"bump_count"];
    NSString *bumpButtonText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bumps ( %@ )",bumpCount];
    [Cell.bumpButton setTitle:bumpButtonText  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    //[Cell.StatusLabel sizeToFit];
    NSString *created_string=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"created"];
    double created_double = created_string.doubleValue;
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:created_double];
    NSString *ago = [date timeAgo];
    Cell.timeLabel.text=ago;




    //Cell.DefaultImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buhz_mini_logo.png"];

    [Cell.DefaultImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumb_url]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]];
    return Cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Ideally you should do lazy loading so that instead of creating a new textView each time, you just reuse the same one.
    UITextView *temp = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(82, 26, self.FeedTable.frame.size.width, 18)]; //This initial size doesn't matter
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self->feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *status = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
    temp.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:12];
    temp.text = status;
    [temp isHidden];

    CGFloat textViewWidth = 218;
    CGRect tempFrame = CGRectMake(82,26,textViewWidth,18); //The height of this frame doesn't matter.
    CGSize tvsize = [temp sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tempFrame.size.width, tempFrame.size.height)]; //This calculates the necessary size so that all the text fits in the necessary width.

    //Add the height of the other UI elements inside your cell

    return tvsize.height + 70;


}

@end
```

**CUSTOM FeedItemCell.M**

```
#import "FeedItemCell.h"
#import "WYPopoverController/WYPopoverController.h"
#import "WYPopoverController/WYStoryboardPopoverSegue.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"


@interface FeedItemCell() <WYPopoverControllerDelegate>
{

    WYPopoverController* commentsPopoverController;
}
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender;
- (void)close:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation FeedItemCell
@synthesize commentButton;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}




-(IBAction)bump:(id)sender{

    [self expand];

}

- (IBAction)open:(id)sender
{
    [self showpopover:sender];
}

- (void)close:(id)sender
{
    [commentsPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    commentsPopoverController.delegate = nil;
    commentsPopoverController = nil;
}

-(void)expand
{
    CGRect  oldFrame = [self frame];

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(  oldFrame.origin.x,
                              oldFrame.origin.y,
                              oldFrame.size.width,
                              oldFrame.size.height * 2)];
}




-(void)contract
{
    CGRect  oldFrame = [self frame];

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(  oldFrame.origin.x,
                              oldFrame.origin.y,
                              oldFrame.size.width,
                              oldFrame.size.height / 2)];
}


- (IBAction)showpopover:(id)sender
{
    if (commentsPopoverController == nil)
    {
        UIView *btn = (UIView*)sender;
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        CommentsViewController *commentsViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Comments"];
        commentsViewController.msg_id=_msg_id;


        if ([commentsViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredContentSize:)]) {
            commentsViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500);             // iOS 7
        }
        else {
            commentsViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 500);      // iOS < 7
        }


        commentsViewController.title = @"Comments";
        [commentsViewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(close:)]];

        commentsViewController.modalInPopover = NO;

        UINavigationController* contentViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:commentsViewController];

        commentsPopoverController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
        commentsPopoverController.delegate = self;
        commentsPopoverController.passthroughViews = @[btn];
        commentsPopoverController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        commentsPopoverController.wantsDefaultContentAppearance = NO;

        [commentsPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.bounds
                                                   inView:btn
                                 permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionNone
                                                 animated:YES
                                                  options:WYPopoverAnimationOptionFadeWithScale];


    }


    else
    {
        [self close:nil];
    }
}
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(WYPopoverController *)controller
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(WYPopoverController *)controller
{
    if (controller == commentsPopoverController)
    {
        commentsPopoverController.delegate = nil;
        commentsPopoverController = nil;
    }
}



@end
```

Comment: Is the "Bump" button supposed to expand the cell? A cell should never modify its own frame.  The button should use the delegate pattern to notify your view controller that you button wants to be bigger.  Then the view controller should return a different value from `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for that cell, and call `[self.FeedTable beginUpdates]; [self.FeedTable endUpdates];`.

Comment: thank you for the side comment, but this does nothing when it comes to finding a actual solution for the problem im trying to solve. Th e issue isnt that I cant get a cell to resize, its that I cant give a cell a popdown menu WHILE keeping my autolayout constraints that make sure the labels frame is big enough to display all the text. If I were to implement the solution from github on my cells as they are now then when you expanded the cell it would also stretch the label out more than needed causing it to either overlap the comment & bump button

Comment: NOTE: the comment & bump buttons are NOT the popdown menu I want to displayed when the cell is expanded , those 2 buttons should always be displayed , the menu i want to add would be a set of 4 buttons that would display under those buttons when the cell is expanded.

Comment: Can you show the autolayout constraints you’re using for the label?

Comment: nvm ... just realized it dint show , will update now

Comment: Added the image that shows the constraints in my original question(3rd img down)

Comment: What happens when the cell gets expanded? Do the bump and comment buttons stay where they are? And the label, does it move at all? Could you show what happens? Or are you expanding the cell at all?

Comment: What constraints do you add when you attempt to expand?

Comment: how many qyestions must i answer b4 anyone actually gives a answer?